# iframe не пропускает сайт - ошибка The reference to entity "pin" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: javascript, java, frontend, iframe

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://hujjat.uz/doc.jsp?id=61ef8a6d-a4f0-4cd0-89b3-89943cb2f379&pin=dY56sK24&sp=1" 
      width="600px" height="400px" style="border: 1px solid gray" />
```

> это zul файл
>   zk framework
>   на официальном сайте тестирую проходит
>   у меня в CRM не пропускает
>   никогда не сталкивался с такой проблемой

Comment: В браузере этот пример прекрасно работает

Comment: попробуйте `&` заменить на `&amp;`

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло)